using rabbit mq for pub/sub with dapr
I need a simple example of using dapr, rabbitmq and python to post a message to a queue.  I have dapr installed, a docker rabbitmq image, a dapr rabbitmq component configured, but my python client just fails.  I know rabbitmq works, because I can connect to it via pika as shown in the python script.  I can also access the rabbitmq admin interface via the browser.
The rabbitmq.yaml file, the python script and the dapr run command are below.  I'm just during ```dapr run``, I'm just trying to run only a sidecar to talk to rabbitmq.
I just get error messages
"Health check on http://127.0.0.1:3500/v1.0/healthz/outbound failed: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it"
and then
"Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\source\dapr_scratch\daprpubsub.py", line 13, in 
with DaprClient() as dapr_client:
^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\source\dapr_scratch\env\Lib\site-packages\dapr\clients_init_.py", line 83, in init
super().init(address, interceptors, max_grpc_message_length, retry_policy)
File "C:\source\dapr_scratch\env\Lib\site-packages\dapr\clients\grpc\client.py", line 139, in init
DaprHealth.wait_until_ready()
File "C:\source\dapr_scratch\env\Lib\site-packages\dapr\clients\health.py", line 47, in wait_until_ready
raise TimeoutError(f'Dapr health check timed out, after {timeout}.')
TimeoutError: Dapr health check timed out, after 60.0."
dapr is configured in the windows defender firewall
apiVersion: dapr.io/v1alpha1
kind: Component
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq-pubsub
  namespace: default
spec:
  type: pubsub.rabbitmq
  version: v1
  metadata:
  - name: connectionString
    value: "amqp://localhost:5672"
  - name: username
    value: guest
  - name: password
    value: guest

import json
import pika
from dapr.clients import DaprClient

try:
    pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters('localhost'))
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
print("connected to RabbitMQ")

# create dapr client and pub/sub a messages
data = {"message": "Hello World"}
with DaprClient() as dapr_client:
    resp = dapr_client.publish_event(pubsub_name='=rabbitmq-pubsub', topic_name='TOPIC_A', data=json.dumps(data))


I am taking a guess here that you are running your application and RMQ in a containerised environment? Likely docker compose? If so, RabbitMQ won't be accessible via localhost as within the context of your Dapr application, that is pointing to itself. Likely, it will be able to discover RabbitMQ using the container name. So normally what you'd do in the compose file is specify something like:
services:
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3-management
    container_name: rabbitmq

And then your Dapr Pub/Sub component YAML will read as follows:
apiVersion: dapr.io/v1alpha1
kind: Component
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq-pubsub
  namespace: default
spec:
  type: pubsub.rabbitmq
  version: v1
  metadata:
  - name: connectionString
    value: "amqp://rabbitmq:5672"
  - name: username
    value: guest
  - name: password
    value: guest

Hope this helps :)
